# Trouble populating a model with a dictionary item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a couple of classes I'm having difficulty populating:

```
   public class ta_Room
   {
    public string url { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string room_code { get; set; }
   }

   public class ta_Hotel2
   {
    public int hotel_id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ta_Room> room_types { get; set; }
   }
```

In my controller I have:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ta_Hotel2 hotel_inventory() //int api_version, string lang)
    {
        {
            ta_Room room = new ta_Room();
            room.price = 23;
            room.room_code = "1";
            room.url = "http://www.nme.com";

            ta_Hotel2 hotel = new ta_Hotel2();
            hotel.room_types.Add("Single", room);
```

However I get a NullReferenceException on the last line above.

In the screenshot below, it shows both the hotel and room object have been created - can anyone please advise what I've done wrong please?

Thank you,

Mark

[image: ss]

Comment: you should initialize dictionary before adding values to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the fact you are not building the instance of `room_types` inside `ta_Hotel2`. You should add a constructor as follows or just instantiate it within `hotel_inventory()`:

```
public class ta_Hotel2
{
    public int hotel_id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, ta_Room> room_types { get; set; }

    public ta_Hotel2()
    {
       room_types = new Dictionary<string, ta_Room>();
    }
}
```

Also note that, from an encapsulation point of view, I would also make the setter of `room_types` private after that. And, as a side note, I would also rename your classes and members as suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a value to **hotel.room_types** before you initialize. Like the way Efran suggest, use a public constructor in **ta_Hotel2** class will solve your issue.